# build/make/core/main.mk:2010: error: writing to readonly directory: "general-tests" while build android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I get this error while build android source code:

```
build/make/core/main.mk:2010: error: writing to readonly directory: "general-tests"
```

my step:
make j1

```
16:53:55 ************************************************************
16:53:55 You are building on a machine with 16GB of RAM
16:53:55 
16:53:55 The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
16:53:55 and even with that, some configurations may not work.
16:53:55 
16:53:55 If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
16:53:55 -j value.
16:53:55 ************************************************************
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:198: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been 
deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:199: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has 
been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=Tiramisu
PLATFORM_VERSION=Tiramisu
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-20.6.0-x86_64-11.6
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=AOSP.MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/generic/goldfish device/generic/goldfish-opengl 
hardware/google/camera hardware/google/camera/devices/EmulatedCamera
============================================
[100% 6/6] writing build rules ...
FAILED: 
build/make/core/main.mk:2010: error: writing to readonly directory: "general-tests"
16:54:03 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (10 seconds) ####
```

In my local folder, can not find "general-tests" directory, and i give folder all permission(use chmod -R a+rwx xxx)

I found file ".repo/manifests/.git/config",and it's content:

```sh
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process --skip
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "default"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/android-11.0.0_r48
[repo "syncstate.main"]
    synctime = 2021-11-11T09:00:43.526381Z
    version = 1
[repo "syncstate.sys"]
    argv = ['/Volumes/Code/AndroidSource/.repo/repo/main.py', '--repo-dir=/Volumes/Code/AndroidSource/.repo', '--wrapper-version=2.17', '--wrapper-path=/Users/lu/bin/repo', '--', 'sync', '-j1']
[repo "syncstate.superproject"]
    superproject = false
    haslocalmanifests = true
    hassuperprojecttag = true
[repo "syncstate.options"]
    jobs = 1
    mpupdate = true
    clonebundle = true
    retryfetches = 0
    repoverify = true
    quiet = false
    verbose = false
[repo "syncstate.remote.origin"]
    url = https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[repo "syncstate.branch.default"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I build Aops with MacOs 12 after changed file "/build/soong/cc/config/darwin_host.go"

```golang
darwinSupportedSdkVersions = []string{
        "11",
        "12",//I add this line
    }
```

Comment: Which Android release/branch you are trying to build? Please specify your BUILD_ID from `build/make/core/build_id.mk`

Comment: i trying to build branch master, BUILD_ID=AOSP.MASTER

Comment: Just to understand the background better. Why you may want to build the master branch? As I know it's not a release branch and even not Google's development branch.